# AWS: Can't connect to Elastic IP after reassigning it to another instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, tcp, elastic-ip

**So I have an Elastic IP which was assigned to another instance. I deleted this instance without releasing the elastic ip from it, created another instance and assigned it.**

1. I can ssh into the instance, the app is running on port 3000.
2. I have checked the security group, port 3000 is open to all with
   custom TCP protocol.

***I cannot connect to it in browser?!***

Am I missing a step? Please help.

Comment: Since you can connect via SSH, the Elastic IP address is working fine. It would probably be related to your application. You can try `curl localhost:3000` from the instance to confirm that it is running, then from your own browser try `http://<EIP-ADDRESS>:3000`

Answer (score 0):

Resolved, there was an error in the application code.